# Best for ASP.NET MVC, Entity Framework or ADO.NET?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, ado.net

I'll start developing websites using ASP.NET MVC, and I wondered about what is the best (or most appropriate) technology to connect with the database to use in MVC, Entity Framework or ADO.NET? and why?

Comment: Add some details for your question or it will be closed as too general..do you have a specific use case? tell us what you are thinking and what you need

Comment: Ok thanks, I'll add the details now.

Comment: This is still quite a generalised question - what sort of application? Is the data complicated? are you building on existing code, or starting from scratch? For example, EF is great for quickly building and maintaining simple databases, but if you are going to require Stored Procedures, Views, complex indexes etc then there is less advantage in using it over plain old ADO.NET directly

Comment: Updated my answer after your clarification

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These are apples and oranges.

Entity Framework is an open source ORM (object relational mapping framework) that targets ADO.NET which is part of MS .NET framework. [LINK](http://www.asp.net/entity-framework)

On the other hand ASP.NET MVC is a web application framework that implements the MVC (model view controller) pattern. [LINK](http://www.asp.net/mvc)

ASP.NET MVC applications that need data access can use Entity Framework or other ORM.

Alternatively ASP.NET MVC developers can use traditional ADO.NET technics for data access.

**UPDATE:**

There is no best or more appropriate suggestion. It all depends on your needs and mostly your application needs.

Using traditional ADO.NET (with datareaders , datatables e.t.c) is surely an option but it will consume time from you , time that you could dedicate in other areas on your application.

Personally what i do is the following:

-For small to medium projects i use a micro ORM. My favorite is [DAPPER](https://github.com/StackExchange/dapper-dot-net)

-For bigger projects i go with Entity Framework.

-In cases where Entity Framework driver is not available (like AS400 which i work a lot with) i use DAPPER.

-In really simple cases [SQLite](https://www.google.gr/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CB4QFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.sqlite.org%2F&ei=Iu1LVJfnDYr6ygPao4HQDg&usg=AFQjCNEakQjCFFXx7pu-fq8qk9wUOlC1Bg&sig2=RQ5EHEIR41OfwjzX2FNJAA&bvm=bv.77880786,d.bGQ) + Dapper is a saver.